# How can I fix my Planet Gravity Script? (C#)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

My Planet Gravity script does nothing when executed, I've tested this, and it is because rb is getting something assigned to it and the force isn't being applied, or there is something else wrong. I am pretty new to Unity and C# so there is probably many things horribly wrong with this script. I am trying to make a "Mario Galaxy" inspired 2D platformer with individual planet gravity. This is not entirely my script, I found a script that suited my needs but it was in 3D so I heavily modified it to turn it into 2D but it has yet to work. Any help would be greatly appreciated as I am still learning and wishing to improve.

Here is the Script:

```
public class PlanetGravity : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float PullRadius;
    public float GravitationalPull;
    public float MinRadius;
    public float DistanceMultiplier;
    
    public LayerMask LayersToPull;
    
    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        Collider2D[] colliders = Physics2D.OverlapCircleAll(transform.position, PullRadius, LayersToPull);

        for (var i = 0; i < colliders.Length; i++)
        {
            Rigidbody2D rb = colliders[i].GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();

            if (rb == null) continue;

            Vector2 direction = transform.position - colliders[i].transform.position;

            if (direction.magnitude < MinRadius) continue;

            float distance = direction.sqrMagnitude * DistanceMultiplier + 1;

            rb.AddForce(direction.normalized * (GravitationalPull / distance) * rb.mass * Time.fixedDeltaTime);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are there any errors given by the debugger? You have `rb = null` instead of `rb==null`, which should be alerted to you by a debugger.

Comment: You want help 'fixing' things but haven't described what's wrong.

Comment: Lmao, thank you @ChilliPenguin, I was having an error in the console but that fixed it. Even with that fixed though the script still doesn't work. :(

Comment: Thank you @asawyer, I've added that.

Comment: Again "still doesn't work" doesn't tell us anything. I'd venture a guess that the `return` statements might need to be `continue` as you could just be quitting out of the loop to early. Please edit your question with clear and exact descriptions of both expected behavior and what you have observed. Include any errors and all attempts to fix and debug that you have already done.

Answer (score 2):

I fixed it. After the comments and help from @asawyer and @ChilliPenguin, all I had to do was input a bigger number for the `GravitationalPull` Variable and it worked.